# Display ManagedBean attribute in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I have a session managed bean called `personne` and I would like to display the `name` property in my JSP file. But I've no idea of how I could do that...

Thanks for your help,

ed

Comment: Your question is too general to be answered in a helpful way. Please update your question with relevant snippets of your bean and the JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h:outputText value="#{personne.name}" />
```

Comment: Hi GriffeyDog, I already tried this way but it literally displays nothing for me... So I thought it was the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I used out.println() to display the name property when getter is called, and apparently its null :s